# Como esperar que la validacion de la bucle while se complete antes de la proxima ejecucion de codigo

Tags: c#, webservice, email

Tengo un programa en el cual cuando valida una condicion en la bucle while, si es true este debe mandar correos electronicos.

Esto funciona bien, pero lo que deseo es que una vez que la validacion del while termine, recien pueda ejecutar el codigo de envio de correos electronicos.

En este momneto me funciona bien, pero al ejecutarse inmediatamente, los correos se me envian en duplicados cada vez que la bucle while es ejecutada, por lo tanto recibo muchos correos electonicos en vez de recibir solo uno.

Como puedo hacer esto?

Aqui esta un ejemplo de mi codigo:

```
while ((userData[userIDindex].ToString().Equals("3", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) ||
userData[userIDindex].ToString().Equals("4", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)))
{
    toEmailAdresses.Add(xml.GetElementsByTagName("toEmailAdresses")[t].InnerText);
    //apiKey.Add(xml.GetElementsByTagName("apiKey")[i].InnerText);
    fromEmailAddress = xml.GetElementsByTagName("fromEmailAddress")[t].InnerText;
    bodyMessage = xml.GetElementsByTagName("bodyMessage")[t].InnerText;
    //(String.Join(",", fromEmailAddress[t].ToArray())));
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(fromEmailAddress, toEmailAdresses[t].ToString());
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
    client.Port = 25;
    client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    client.Host = "localhost"; //here goes the smpt connection
    mail.Subject = "Testing email";
    mail.Body = bodyMessage;
    client.Send(mail);

} //end of the while
```

Comment: entra al bucle cuando userData[userIDindex] es 3 o 4 pero en que momento cambias el valor para que pueda salir del bucle

Comment: tal vez se envian en duplicado porque cumplen las dos condiciones? falta codigo para saber cual es tu problema real aca. El codigo que subiste no funciona.

Comment: lo que pasa que cuando el codigo llama al servicio el userData[userIDindex] va a cambiar a otro valor que no sea 3 o 4 y es ahi cuando la bucle se temina y no ejecuta mas

Answer (score 1):

Si no estoy equivocado (y no usas algún código que no muestras en algún método no documentado que te modifica `userIDindex`) probablemente no quieres usar `while`, pero `if`.

Más que nada, si como dices, te "funciona bien, solamente envía los correos dos veces", es seguro que cambias algo en `ToString` o `Equals`.

En un bucle `while` deberías tener un valor que cambia la condición, si no tienes un `while` en la mayoría de los casos poco útil, uno que corre nunca o siempre. Para eso no necesitarías tanto código en la condición, un `while(true)` (corre siempre) o un `while(false)` (corre nunca) serían más obvio.

Answer (score 0):

Creas una Función llamada EnviarCorreo

> Esta Funcion Booleana Recibe el destinatario, asunto,cuerpo y la copia

```
     public bool EnviarCorreo(string To, string Asunto, string Cuerpo, string copiado)
    {
        bool EnviadoCorrectamente = true;
        try
        {
            string smtpAddress = "smtp.gmail.com";
            int portNumber = 587;
            bool enableSSL = true;
            string emailTo = To;
            using (MailMessage mail2 = new MailMessage())
            {
                mail2.From = new MailAddress("tumail");
                mail2.To.Add(emailTo);
                if (copiado != "") { mail2.CC.Add(copiado); }
                mail2.Subject = Asunto;
                mail2.Body = Cuerpo;
                mail2.IsBodyHtml = true;
                using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(smtpAddress, portNumber))
                {
                    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("tumail", "tupass");
                    smtp.EnableSsl = enableSSL;
                    smtp.Send(mail2);
                }
            }
        }
        catch { EnviadoCorrectamente = false; }
        return EnviadoCorrectamente;
    }
```

Posteriormente solo la mandas a llamar

```
if(userData[userIDindex].ToString().Equals("3") || userData[userIDindex].ToString().Equals("4"))
 {
 bool procesoenv = EnviarCorreo(mail_rest, subject, body, label1.Text);
  if (procesoenv)
    {
    MessageBox.Show("CORRECTAMENTE ENVIADO");
    }
    else
     {
      MessageBox.Show("Ha habido un error al enviar el correo");                      
     }
 }
 //Termina el Proceso
```

Comment: no esta mal.. pero no veo que solucione el problema que tiene..

Comment: Hola gracias por tu respuesta. Me parece bien, pero me envia de todas maneras el correo y lo que necesito esque solamente se envie despues que la bucle while haya terminado por completa su validacion y solamente mande el correo despues que la bucle termine la ejecucion

Comment: @Aarancibia un bucle no se usa para validar, se usa para recorrer elementos o hacer cosas mientras se cumpla una condicion, a que te referis con validar?

Comment: me imagino que puedes mezclar el do while y fuera de el colocar el codigo que necesitas

Comment: @gbianchi, tienes razon al decirme que no deberia usarse para validar. De que forma podria validarlo?

Comment: usaria un for. checa mi edicion

Comment: Para verificar algo se usa un if. No hay otra forma de verificar una condicion (un case en el caso de condiciones multiples)